# SOLR wildcard search not returning results

Tags: solr

I have a schema definition as follows:

```
<fieldType name="textSuggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([,]+)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>      
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>          
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([,]+)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

And some data in the format:

```
17,WALKINGTON,AVENUE,,MARGARET RIVER,WA
```

If I search for 17 walkington, it shows the above in the results. How can I make sure that if I search for 17 walk, the above shows up in the search results? I have tried appending * at the end of the search query, but can't get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you do wildcard searches, analysis generally does not happen (except for filters that are multitermaware). You might want to look at the complexphrasequeryparser or use an ngram/edgengram-filter with a tokenizer that keeps most of the token instead (and replace `,` - it depends on what kind of queries you think people will need to do)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the partial word match you have to change or add the ngram filter.

Try using ngram filter.

Factory class: `solr.NGramFilterFactory`

for example the Arguments of it:

minGramSize: (integer, default 1) The minimum n-gram size, must be > 0.

maxGramSize: (integer, default 2) The maximum n-gram size, must be >= minGramSize.

Example you can a field type for your field:

```
<fieldType name="textSuggest" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([,]+)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>      
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="10"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>          
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([,]+)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Note : The ngram causes big number of tokens and hence large index size if you have huge data set.

Comment: I have just over 15 million records in the data set.

Comment: Should be ok...hope you have the good infra support as well